# Aurora mySQL max_connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to increase the max_connections of an aurora mySQL instance.
According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Performance.html) it's possible, but I can't find it anywhere in parameter groups. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aurora clusters use two parameter groups -- one for the cluster and one for the instances.  `max_connections` is in the instance parameter group -- not the cluster group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups